# What does ~* and | mean in SQL translate syntax

Tags: sql, translate

```
select * 
from table
where translate(columnA, ' ', '') ~* translate('(HR Department|RD Department|Training|Sales|Science)',' ','')
```

What does the above where clause mean? I know ~* means 'like'.

From the result, I know it selects the records where columnA in 'HR Department'....

but not sure, what does "|" mean in the second translate syntax.

Thanks,

Comment: It's like "or" condition, it will check is those table

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

`~*` is **not** `like`.  It is a case insensitive regular expression comparison -- at least in Postgres.  I'm not sure if any other databases support this operator with a different meaning.

The `translate()` is simply removing spaces.

The comparison:

```
columnA ~ '(HR Department|RD Department|Training|Sales|Science)'
```

Is doing regular expression matching.  It is true when `columnA` contains any of the substrings between the vertical bars -- `'HR Department', 'RD Department' and so on.  The vertical bars themselves mean "or" in a regular expression.

Of course, in your actual comparison is case insensitive (the `~*` operation instead of `~`) and ignores spaces.